# Command line approach to taking a 16:9 video and creating a 1080x1920 YouTube short?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, short

Is there a way of using ffmpeg or similar, taking a 1920x1080 video, cut out the middle bit for creating a 1080x1920 YouTube short and then getting it to upscale the middle bit?

EDIT: I think this is it:
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1080:1080:420:0,scale=1920:1920:flags=lanczos:param0=3,crop=1080:1920" -acodec copy output.mp4

Comment: "cut out the middle bit" you mean cropping? Or edit in time?

Comment: Cropping, I've edited the question with what looks like the right approach.

Comment: And did you have success with this command?

Comment: Yeah, I've adopted an approach of converting the whole video with the command above first and then selecting out the 59 seconds I want with a follow up command.  That does the trick.  YouTube is now recognising the videos as shorts.